# Why Excel graphs are adding empty data points?

Tags: excel, graph

I want to plot the sales on specific dates. But of course there hasn't been sales on some weekends and holidays, so i dont want to plot these days. Just skip these days in the graph. But as soon as i create a bar chart in excel and select the data points, excel automatically put the other dates in without data. How can i force excel to show only the data points i provide?
I attached to data point and the graph which excel creates.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C7hm.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqBVw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In the colum (or row) of data representing your dates, ensure they are string literals and not *date* values. You can do this by prepending a single-quote, e.g.:

```
'14/04/2017
```

Strictly speaking, you only need to do this to the *first* date.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to format the x axis with the following option: Axis Type: **Text Axis**
[image: x axis]